# How To Put XIB in Landscape

Tags: iphone, xib, landscape

Hey,
I am making a view based application. For one of the xib files, I want it to only appear in landscape mode. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the view's Orientation is set to Landscape:
[image]

Comment: so is there a solution for you Marcus?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that this function returns YES or (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
    // Or you can use the following return statement: 
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

And in your Project-info.plist file in resource folder, there will be an option for "Support Interface orientation", set it according to your requirement.